# Compiler not showing error message

Tags: compiler-errors, dev-c++

I am using Dev C++ Version 5.4.2
When I compile any program,it is just highlighting the lines with errors but not giving any error message telling what the error is.I am a complete beginner.Please help here.

Comment: Can you provide us more information? Perhaps a screenshot?

Comment: I would have loved to but I am new here and it says I cant post an image without reputation 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-run DevC++, try to compile the project again, then move your mouse cursor to the bottom of the DevC++ window, over the horizontal lines, press the left mouse button and pull up - a toolbar with the error names will appear again. At least this helped me :)